# Java CMYK Voltons

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, cmyk

I don't know if this is already answered in a different question, but i did not find anything about it.

My Goal is to create a valid PDF-X1a / PDF-X3 document via iText 2.1.7
I used JAI to convert a RGB Image to CMYK and im also able to create a PDF-X document. The Validator of Acrobat Pro is pointing out that my Image that i converted contains, special colors (Volton in Adobe) that are not in the CMYK ColorSpace. These colors need to be declared separatly. Is there a possible solution to do this with java and give the image the needed information?

At the moment my conversion looks like that

```
BufferedImage rgbImage = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedImage cmykImage = null;
byte[] imageInByte = new byte[0];
try {
  rgbImage = ImageIO.read(image);
  ColorSpace cpace = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(_iccCmykProfile.getInputStream()));
  ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(cpace, null);
  cmykImage = op.filter(rgbImage, null);
  JAI.create("encode", cmykImage, baos, "TIFF");
  baos.flush();
  imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
  baos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return imageInByte;
```

Comment: Not sure you ever solved this, but your question isn't very clear. To begin with, PDF/X-1a and PDF/X-3 are vastly different. You'll have to define what you want. Secondly, it would be good to have an example document that shows exactly what goes wrong as "Volton" is not something I recognise at ell in terms of color.

Answer (score -2):

It's an additive version of CMYK, but i hope it works.

```
var cmyk = function (cyan, magenta, yellow, key) {    
    var red = magenta*255 + yellow*255 - cyan*255 - key*(255*2.2);
    var green = cyan*255 + yellow*255 - magenta*255 - key*(255*2.2);
    var blue = magenta*255 + cyan*255 - yellow*255 - key*(255*2.2);
    fill (red, green, blue);
};
```